# Where do I find the "Amazon Cognito Identity ID" referred to in the Amplify Storage documentation?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

The [Amplify Storage documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/configureaccess/q/platform/js/) describes the rubric for S3 paths to files including `user_identity_id` for private and protect files. Where can I find the value of that for a given users, and for all users of my app? For example, how would I reconstruct the path to files stored in S3 by `Storage.put` in another context such as a Python notebook?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve identityId from:

```
const { identityId } = await Auth.currentCredentials();
```

see https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/configureaccess/q/platform/js/

The afterwards to reconstruct the the path you would concatenate the identityId and the prefix used from protected, public or private. See the code from the Amplify library how it's implemented:

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/main/packages/storage/src/providers/AWSS3Provider.ts

```
const privatePath =
            (customPrefix.private !== undefined ? customPrefix.private : 'private/') +
            identityId +
            '/';
        const protectedPath =
            (customPrefix.protected !== undefined
                ? customPrefix.protected
                : 'protected/') +
            identityId +
            '/';
        const publicPath =
            customPrefix.public !== undefined ? customPrefix.public : 'public/';
```